# Update string from an object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on mongodb and node.js and i came a across a scenario.

```
{
  "id": "12345678";
  "contract": {
    "decimalSeparator": "dot",
    "thousandSeparator": "comma"
 }
}
```

*how do i only update thousandSeparator. 
which query I need to use*

Answer (score 1):

`$set` is what you need. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

```
db.name.update({
    id: '12345678',
    {
        $set: {
            'contract.thousandSeparator': 'newValue'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How do i select the  "contract". your query does not work for me

Comment: Obviously, you need to change `db.name` with your database name. You asked for a query that does a partial update of a document, the query is `$set` using the path (updated).

Comment: Thanks,  Its works for me